# Как сделать рандом на Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте, мне нужно создать алгоритм рандома на Tkinter, я создал 2 списка из которых программа должна рандомно выбрать одно имя, но я не понимаю как сделать так чтобы она выбирала список опираясь на то что ввел я (на пример если я ввожу 1 то программа выбирает из списка code_list1, и наоборот)

Вот код:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import random

code_list1 = [("Sledge"),("Thatcher"),("Ash"),("Thermite"),
              ("Twitch"),("Montagne"),("Glaz"),("Fuze"),
              ("Blitz"),("IQ"),("Buck"),("Blackbeard"),
              ("Capitao"),("Jackal"),("Ying"),("Zofia"),
              ("Dokkaebi")]

code_list2 = [("Smoke"),("Mute"),("Castle"),("Pulse"),("Doc"),("Rook"),
              ("Tachanka"),("Jager"),("Bandit"),("Frost"),("Valkyrie"),                                               
              ("Echo"),("Mira"),("Ela"),("Lesion"),("Vigil"),("Caveira"),
              ("Kapkan")]


def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()
    mlabe12 = Label(mGui, 
    return


mGui = Tk()
ment = StringVar()

mGui.geometry('450x450+500+300')
mGui.title('R6S Operator Randomizer 2.0')

mlabel = Label(mGui, text='Введите сторону оперативника').pack()

mbutton = Button(mGui,text = 'OK', command = mhello, fg = 
'red',bg='blue').pack()

mEntry = Entry(mGui,textvariable=ment).pack()
mGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи функции [`len(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=len#len) можно узнать количество значений в вашем массиве, а при помощи [`randrange(a,b)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#functions-for-integers) можно задать рандомное значение с точки `a`  до точки `b` на примере вашего кода это будет выглядеть так.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import random

code_list1 = [("Sledge"),("Thatcher"),("Ash"),("Thermite"),
              ("Twitch"),("Montagne"),("Glaz"),("Fuze"),
              ("Blitz"),("IQ"),("Buck"),("Blackbeard"),
              ("Capitao"),("Jackal"),("Ying"),("Zofia"),
              ("Dokkaebi")]
length_code_list1 = len(code_list1)

code_list2 = [("Smoke"),("Mute"),("Castle"),("Pulse"),("Doc"),("Rook"),
              ("Tachanka"),("Jager"),("Bandit"),("Frost"),("Valkyrie"),
              ("Echo"),("Mira"),("Ela"),("Lesion"),("Vigil"),("Caveira"),
              ("Kapkan")]
length_code_list2 = len(code_list2)

def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()

    if mtext == '1':
        number = random.randrange(0, length_code_list1)
        mlabe12.config(text='You name ' + code_list1[number])
    elif mtext == '2':
        number = random.randrange(0, length_code_list2)
        mlabe12.config(text='You name ' + code_list2[number])
    else:
        mlabe12.config(text='Введите либо значение 1 либо значение 2')
    return


mGui = Tk()
ment = StringVar()

mGui.geometry('450x450+500+300')
mGui.title('R6S Operator Randomizer 2.0')

mlabel = Label(mGui, text='Введите сторону оперативника').pack()

mbutton = Button(mGui,text = 'OK', command = mhello, fg =
'red',bg='blue').pack()

mEntry = Entry(mGui,textvariable=ment).pack()
mlabe12 = Label(mGui)
mlabe12.pack()
mGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Для получения случайного значения из последовательности лучше использовать [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice).

Пример получения случайного элемента из списков:

```
import random

item_1 = random.choice(code_list1)
item_2 = random.choice(code_list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = None
if entered_code == 1: 
    rnd = int(random.random() * float(len(code_list1) - 1))
    ret = code_list1[rnd]
elif entered_code == 2: 
    rnd = int(random.random() * float(len(code_list2) - 1))
    ret = code_list2[rnd]
```

А еще лучше объединить два списка в список списков и просто адресовать :

```
rnd = int(random.random() * float(len(code_list[entered_code]) - 1))
ret = code_list[entered_code][rnd]
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае,  идеальным вариантом будет [`random.choice(list_name)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice).

Также в общих чертах можно реализовать так:

```
import random
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rand_num = random.randint(0, len(list) +1)
name = list[rand_num]
```